# Taking the innermost dict in nested dictionary with recursion

Tags: python

Here is my snippet:

```
info = {'k1': {
        'k2': {
            'k3': 'v3',
            'k4': 'v4',
            'k5': 'v5'}
        },
}
```

So I want to use recursion to get the most inner dict `{'k3': 'v3', 'k4': 'v4', k5': 'v5'}`, because I will have dicts with different nested levels, but in any cases I will need to take this the most inner dictionary. How can I do that?

Here is my try:

```
def recursion(info):
    store = dict()
    for key in info.keys():
        if isinstance(info[key], dict):
            recursion(info[key])
        store[key] = info[key]
return store
```

Comment: How are this dicts available? like are you reading them from some file or are they arranged in a column of a dataframe?

Comment: Sorry, from var, I added my not working solution

Comment: In your attempt, should `store[key] = info[key]` be inside the for loop?

Comment: yeah, it is, my bad when paste it

Comment: I think you probably got a TypeError when you tried running that code. *store = dict* is part of your problem

Comment: I added `()` it doen't break now but gives me that output `{'k1': {'k2': {'k3': 'v3', 'k4': 'v4', 'k5': 'v5'}}}`

Answer (score 0):

One option:

```
def inner_most(d):
    def inner_most_helper(d, level = 0):
        ' Use recursion to find dictionary at highest inner level'
        # Max level starts with current dictionary
        level_max, d_max = level, d
        for k, v in d.items():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                # Found a higher level of nesting
                level_, d_ = inner_most_helper(v, level + 1)
                if level_ > level_max:
                    d_max = d_
        return level_max, d_max
    
    return inner_most_helper(d)[1]
```

**Test**

```
d = {'k1': {
        'k2': {
            'k3': 'v3',
            'k4': 'v4',
            'k5': 'v5'}
        },
}
print(inner_most(d))  # print inner most dictionary
```

*Output*

{'k3': 'v3', 'k4': 'v4', 'k5': 'v5'}

Comment: When I put var `info` in you function I get this output `(0, {'k3': 'v3', 'k4': 'v4', 'k5': 'v5'})`

Comment: My function returns a tuple of the `(level, nested_dict)`.  To get the nested dict you take index 1 of the tuple returned, thus, `inner_most(info)[1]` as shown in my test example.

Comment: @htodev   Modified by so it handles ignores the level for you.  So now you can just use: `inner_most(info)`

Comment: I think @Stackpy s solution is the simplest and cleanest one

Comment: @htodev That solution was deleted.  Looking at the deleted version that solution does not work in general.  For instance, remove keys 'k4' and 'k5' from the innermost dictionary.  That solution incorrectly prints 'v3'.

Comment: yes, you are right

Answer (score 0):

If it would be sufficient to find a dictionary that doesn't have any dictionary nested inside it, you can do this:

```
def get_childless_dicts(d):
    has_child = False
    for v in d.values():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            yield from get_childless_dicts(v)
            has_child = True
    if not has_child:
        yield d
```

This yields any childless dicts, so if you know there is only one you can get only the first one using `next`:

```
print(next(get_childless_dicts(info)))
```

Comment: I think @Stackpy s solution is the simplest and cleanest one

Comment: Stackpy 's deleted solution found the only dictionary with more than one key, whether inner-most or not.